# Postgres query to find max value of a column and group by an ID, only if the date for that max value is the Max(dt) for the table. works in sqllite3

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, stock

I have a query in sqlite3 that works, but I can't get the query to work on postgres. The purpose of the query is find if a stock has hit its new high for the Max(Date) in the table. ie the last date for which stock prices were updated. So Monday, would look at Friday's day.
SQLite3 query that works:

```
SELECT * from ( 
            select symbol, name, stock_id, min(close), dt
            FROM day_stock_price join stock on stock.id = day_stock_price.stock_id 
            GROUP by stock_id
            ORDER By symbol
            ) where dt = (select max(dt) from day_stock_price)
```

```
                  Table "public.day_stock_price"
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 stock_id  | integer                     |           | not null | 
 dt        | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 open      | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 high      | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 low       | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 close     | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 volume    | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 insqueeze | boolean                     |           |          |
```

At first I thought this was getting closer but it does NOT return the Maximum close price. I was just trying to get the max(close) for each stock_id.

```
select distinct on (stock_id) max(close), dt from day_stock_price Group by stock_id, dt;
```

In the result the first row returned was the max.

```
stock_id |  max  |         dt          
----------+-------+---------------------
        2 | 10.51 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00
        3 | 0.716 | 2020-05-05 00:00:00
```

but the second stock as a max of 14, which I found by selecting all closes for stock_id=3 in DESC order.
That brings me to a very similar Postgres query that does run:

```
SELECT * from ( 
            select symbol, name, stock_id, max(close), dt
            FROM day_stock_price join stock on stock.id = day_stock_price.stock_id 
            GROUP by stock_id, symbol, name, dt
            ORDER By symbol
            ) as X where dt = (select max(dt) from day_stock_price)
```

The answer is just totally wrong. This returns the close value for every stock for the max(dt).  What is wanted that is its only returned if its the Max(Close) AND also the MAX(Dt).

This seems far harder than it should be, so I think I'm just going about this in a very non-Postgres way. I'm new to postgres obviously. I appreciate the help.

Data in day_stock_price looks like this:

```
stockdb=# select * from day_stock_price limit 10;
 stock_id |         dt          |  open  |  high   |  low  | close  |  volume  | insqueeze 
----------+---------------------+--------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-----------
     4165 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 |   2.02 |    2.31 |  1.87 |  1.965 | 21271087 | f
     4165 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 |   1.71 |    2.04 |  1.59 | 1.8911 | 15867773 | f
     4165 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 |   1.65 |    1.73 |  1.51 | 1.6999 |  8824377 | f
     4165 | 2021-01-29 00:00:00 |   1.63 |    1.86 |  1.54 | 1.5899 |  9848362 | f
     4165 | 2021-01-28 00:00:00 |   1.53 |    1.77 |  1.49 | 1.5701 |  8900787 | f
     4666 | 2021-02-03 00:00:00 |   26.9 | 26.9738 |  26.9 | 26.932 |    15695 | f
     4666 | 2021-02-02 00:00:00 | 26.885 |  26.895 | 26.88 | 26.895 |     1500 | f
     4666 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00 | 26.875 |  26.885 | 26.86 | 26.885 |     1850 | f
     4666 | 2021-01-29 00:00:00 |  26.87 |    26.9 |  26.8 |  26.83 |   120001 | f
     4666 | 2021-01-28 00:00:00 |  26.86 |   26.87 | 26.86 |  26.87 |      831 | f
(10 rows)
```

In sqlite3 the response was something like this ( I can't re-run it)

| Symbol | Name | Stock_id | Max(Close) | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | Apple | 5 | 103.89 | 2020-05-05 |
| INTC | Intel | 9 | 56.89 | 2020-05-05 |

The date would ALWAYS be the same because its the max date in the DB.

So its finding the stocks who hit a new high in the last trading day.

Comment: Answering would be easier if you provided example data in `day_stock_price` and an expected result.

Comment: I update the question, I think with what you are asking. Its a fairly straight forward screen, say in tradeview, was pretty straightforward in SQLite, but it is not so for me in postgres. at least not yet.  Thanks

Comment: This is close to workable if I could get the date in a column.  This seems to return the max value for each stock.  I only one the subset that is also max(dt).
select distinct on (stock_id) stock_id, max(close) from day_stock_price group by stock_id limit 10;
 stock_id |   max   
----------+---------
        2 |   10.74
        3 |      14
        4 | 13.9999
        5 |   15.25
        6 | 66.9623
        7 |    4.36
        8 |   25.17
        9 |   27.73
       10 |    6.57
       11 |   66.35
(10 rows)

Comment: This gives the right max(close) values  --   select stock_id, max(close) from day_stock_price group by stock_id limit 10;
 stock_id |   max   
----------+---------
        2 |   10.74
        3 |      14
This shows the right max(dt) -- select stock_id, max(dt) from day_stock_price group by stock_id limit 10;
 stock_id |         max         
----------+---------------------
        2 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00
        3 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00
        4 | 2021-05-04 00:00:00
I want where the Max(close) happens on the max(Dt) grouped by stock_id..

Answer (score 1):

This should return all day_stock_price rows which reached a high on the most recent day. Note that this will return rows that match a prior day exactly; if you want to avoid that, add a filter on `dt < (select max(dt) from day_stock_price)` in the `per_stock_maxes` [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), and change the join condition to `(t1.stock_id=t2.stock_id and t1.close>t2.max_close)`.

```
with today_closes as (
  select * from day_stock_price where dt = (select max(dt) from day_stock_price)
),
per_stock_maxes as (
  select stock_id, max(close) max_close from day_stock_price group by stock_id
)
select t1.* from today_closes t1 join per_stock_maxes t2
  on (t1.stock_id=t2.stock_id and t1.close=t2.max_close)
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I spent hours.. never spent so many hours on something I thought would be so simple. I was not going to get this. I'm going to needs a postgres primer. very helpful.